# How can I build WAR with Maven in Eclipse?

Tags: java, maven-2, web-applications

I have project that I'm now starting as Maven project, but for some reason it is not working. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ProgramName</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProgramName</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- all other dependecies here -->

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>ProgramName</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working, do you have an error message or something?

Comment: how can i build war? i mean i need the war file

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, your POM looks a bit weird:

- it is missing the right `packaging` for a webapp project.
- the maven war plugin configuration doesn't look right, you just don't need the extra stuff you added.

Here is what a minimal pom looks like:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>my-webapp</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

So either modify it and update the project configuration (**right-click** on your project then **Maven > Update Project Configuration**).

Or just start over and create your project using the `maven-archetype-webapp`. You can do this from Eclipse: **New > Project... > Maven Project**, then select the **maven-archetype-webapp** in the wizzard and follow the seps.

Or from the command line:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-webapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

Comment: the element finalName isn't required, it is determent to be <artifactName>-<version>.<packaging>

Comment: Thanx, I removed everything from build and now it seems to work.

Comment: @newbie: You're welcome. Note that you'll need the maven compiler settings for Java 6 though.

Answer (score 5):

for instance, I see

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

missing in your pom, you should have a look at how the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) is used.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/). It's a one click operation using the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: m2eclipse do not integrates maven with WTP. For that of integration you need to used http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/