# Simple Spring MVC Hibernate project using Maven

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, tomcat, maven

I have been trying to follow this tutorial: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/11/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example.html

I did not ran into any problem using the tutorial but my question is: how can I create a war so I can deploy the app in tomcat?

**Edit: I have been able to create the war and deploy it but now when trying to access localhost:8080/MavenWeb I have a 404 page.**

The war is built properly and the name of it is MavenWeb.war, as specified in the finalName tag in the pom.xml file.

Here is the log of tomcat when deploying:

```
May 27, 2012 9:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\lib;C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\\bin;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\lib;.
May 27, 2012 9:32:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 27, 2012 9:32:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 27, 2012 9:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 523 ms
May 27, 2012 9:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 27, 2012 9:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
May 27, 2012 9:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\MavenWeb.war
May 27, 2012 9:32:15 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\MavenWeb\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
May 27, 2012 9:32:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\docs
May 27, 2012 9:32:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\examples
May 27, 2012 9:32:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\host-manager
May 27, 2012 9:32:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\manager
May 27, 2012 9:32:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\ROOT
May 27, 2012 9:32:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 27, 2012 9:32:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 27, 2012 9:32:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2483 ms
```

The welcome file is properly set in the web.xml, I created the corresponding list.jsp and put it in the WEB-INF/jsp folder.

Here is the POM.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Spring3HibernateMaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring3HibernateMaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description></description>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <!-- <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName> -->
    <finalName>MavenWeb</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
      <version>20030825.183949</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

The war is built, I am able to deploy it into Tomcat without any error, but when trying to access it with localhost:8080/MavenWeb/ I only have a white page.

The first page is configured this way under the web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3-Hibernate</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>list.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

So if I properly understand, when accessing localhost:8080/MavenWeb/ I should be directly redirected to list.html

Comment: Hi dukable, that's a very broad question. Perhaps your question would be clearer if you could be more specific about what steps you have already tried?  Good luck! :)

Comment: This *might* help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116605/how-can-i-build-war-with-maven-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did the following on this

Installed Tomcat 6, as the source and target was 1.5 http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Added the role manager-gui to tomcat-users.xml

```
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Then logged in to the `http://localhost:8080/manager/` successfully deploy the  Hello World Servlet, which sadly was of little use to the OP as this code associated with the tutorial was not the finished code. Meh.

I suggested going through [this mvn tutorial from sonatype](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/) as that would build up the Maven skills and knowledge to the point where this first tutorial could be troubleshooted effectively.

Also suggested including references to the pom XSD in pom.xml so that tools could validate the content of same as it was developed.

From the one of sonatype tutorial pom file we have

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
```

Then in IntelliJ, for example, I can enter `< CTRL+SPACE` and get a drop down list of valid elements that part of the file.

Comment: I did edit my first post to explain more. I have been able to create the war, editing the build in the pom.xml file and to deploy it without any issue but can't access the URL http://localhost:8080/ContactManager. It gives me a white page.

Comment: I just posted this answer seconds before your update :) I'll delete this answer if not useful.

Comment: Ok it would be good to post a link to the full pom.xml This will allow us to verify the file.

Comment: I did add it on my first post as well as where I am so far (I am able to deploy the war but unable to access my app when browsing to localhost:8080/ContactManager

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11801/discussion-between-rob-and-dukable)

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify the name of the war that is getting created and deployed on tomcat. 
   Many times maven will create war files with version numbers in it. That impacts the URL to be used.
2. Also, I may be wrong about this, but in the web.xml, shouldn't the URL Pattern be: "/*" instead of just "/"

Comment: I did verify both point and everything seems to be fine. I also added 2 other servlet mappings with *.jsp and *.html

Comment: @dukable what do u get when u go to:
1. localhost:8080/ContactManager

2. localhost:8080/ContactManager/

3. localhost:8080/ContactManager/list.html

Comment: blank page for any of those URLs.

Comment: If even this: "localhost:8080/ContactManager/list.html"  is giving u a blank page, then it means that there is an exception occurring somewhere in tomcat, so the browser gets 0 data in the response. Also .. is there a chance ur request is going via a Proxy app you have installed for debugging?

Comment: I just did realize that ContactManager is the name of the DB, which makes sense to have a blank page when trying to access it... The name of the war is MavenWeb, as shown on my first post on the pom.xml <finalName>MavenWeb</finalName>. However when trying to access localhost:8080/MavenWev I simply have a 404 error. I will copy the log of tomcat in my first post.

Comment: yeah that's why my first post was about war file name.  In tomcat the war file name ends up being app name. Try going to   "localhost:8080/MavenWeb/list.html"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11802/discussion-between-rk2010-and-dukable)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a typo here??

In your web.xml you have specified **list.jsp** as the welcome file list.

But after displaying the web.xml, you have written that the **list.html** is not getting redirected.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your war did not get deployed properly. The startup log says that servlet-api.jar has not loaded correctly. Fix that first and then we can diagnose it a little further.

This is what the log says

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\MavenWeb\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

There seems to be 2 versions of servlet-api jar in your `classpath` and one of them is causing problems. Also you're using `JDK 7`. Please check compatibility of the jars that you are using with JDK 7

I think you have `servlet.jar` and `servlet-api-2.5.jar` in your classpath. Remove `servlet.jar` and you should be rolling.