# Create War Files in Eclipse to run on JBoss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, war

What are the best practices of creating war files (using eclipse) to run on jBoss? tutorials, links, examples are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just go through the links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032421/how-to-create-an-war-file-in-eclipse-without-ant-or-maven)[link2](http://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/eclipse-create-deployable-war-file-for-java-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

Use maven as the build tool (in eclipse). Maven is the de facto standard for java builds. It may be a bit difficult in the beginning, but easy tasks (like building a war file) can be done easily.

An answer of how to do it e.g. here: [How can I build WAR with Maven in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116605/how-can-i-build-war-with-maven-in-eclipse)

Comment: Thanks for reply but i dont want to build using maven.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Do you use the JBoss Tools as an eclipse plugin?

Comment: Yes I am Using "JBoss Tools" Eclipse Plugin