# How to deploy a web application made in jsp and servlet?

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I am developing a web app using JSP (and Servlet).This is the directory structure I am using. I don't know how to make it run as a single app in server by giving login page address in url. Currently, I am able to run seperate pages in server by right click on it and select Run ON server.Please help me. I tried using manager app in tomcat.But, could not.It says authentication failed. I tried keeping the WAR file in webapps folder of tomcat, but when I type in url localhost:8080/mywebapp it shows http error.[image]

Comment: Why don't you use Maven for build. You would be able to create a WAR where you will be able to keep classes and jsp.And it would be more structured.

Comment: @Md Faraz I don't know how to use it.Can you tell me?

Comment: You can go with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116605/how-can-i-build-war-with-maven-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

right click on your project ->run as ->Run on server ! thats it[image]

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on your tomcat configuration. If you have automatic deployment set in it and a you have a built WAR archive, copy the WAR archive into webapp folder and **restart the Tomcat server**. After it has started, you can check if folder with your application has been created in webapp folder and then go to appropriate url.